# How to align modal-menu to hamburger element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, alignment

I have #header-wrapper with max-width: 1500px; and inside there are logo on the left and div with hamburger menu (trigger for modal-menu) on the right. Header has max-width: 1500px so the menu disctance from the right side of screen is different.
I want to align the modal-menu with the div on the right.

[screenshot: what i want and what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D32V0.png)

My structure:

-> header-wrapper (relative)

->-> logo

->-> div

->->-> hamburger-menu

-> modal-menu (absolute)

I think it should be codded in jQuery, please help :(

My website is built with Oxygen (wordpress), here's my testing page and header: [testing page](https://fisite.pl/test/)

Comment: what have you tried please provide your code. edit your question and put your code by clicking <> .

Comment: I added my website. Built in wordpress (oxygen builder)

Comment: I don't know much about the oxygen builder but i'm inspecting your code and I can see that your modal is on the right side.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to align modal on the right side of hamburger div.

Comment: you mean align the right side of the modal push it towards left?? if so on your id  #my-modal {right: 30px;} instead of 0px thats on the code this will move it .

Comment: See screenshot in post. I can align it manually on 1920px screen, but on smaller screens it moves. I'd like to keep the same distance both hamburger and modal

Comment: Since your code is inline you need to add like this @media (max-width: 1200px){
#my-modal {
    width: 20%;
    top: 128px !important;
}}

Comment: seems like your code have  break points on 1200 and 991 inline code of style="top: calc(0% + 139.375px);" i would rethink things and make things easy for you. like more responsive and not gonna call a bunch of media calls. Its a pain to do that heres another one  @media (max-width: 991px){
#my-modal {
    width: 20%;
    top: 117px !important;
    right: adjust it here.}}

Comment: Okay @Crystal, now I see everything is okay under 1500px. But between 1500 and 1920 hambyrger has different distance. I cant get it by media query breakpoints

Comment: since its working on 1500px max-width, call it media (max-width 1920px){{ your css here }} or media (min-width:1501px)